Is this chandelier incorrectly wired?
After moving into my house I noticed that the chandelier light appeared to have a short in it, I've been avoiding switching the light on until I could take a look at what's going on. When I got up there I found the black wire didn't appear connected to anything and there are three white wires coming out of the ceiling connected to one wire from the light. Also there appears to be a second wire from the light connecting to nothing which I'm assuming got pulled out of the black. I will send some pictures but all in all I'm confused by the setup. Is this even properly wired? 




I'll try to take More but not sure I can get any better angles. The first photo shows the chandelier. Two wires co-op the chandelier. The second photo shows how the wire on the right coming out of the chandelier is not connected into anything and the black wire coming out of the ceiling is also disconnected. The third photo shows the three white wires coming out of the ceiling that are connected to The second wire from the chandelier attached with the wire nut and a lot of electrical tape. I have no idea why the three wires would be attached to one wire from the chandelier.

The group of white wire is probably the neutrals and would have a wire from the light connected to them. You have another wire nut up in there that probably has a few black wires and maybe a white one for  switch loop.  Those extra wires feed other parts of the house and  the two wires not connected should probably be connected but you'd have to verify all this.

It is difficult to tell from the pictures exactly how things are wired. But there is an indication that there is a problem.
This picture showing the wires coming from the chandelier show the typical two-wire lamp cord and a third bare wire for ground:

This picture shows where one of the lamp cord wires is in physical contact with the metal support and possibly screwed down under the ground screw:

If this chandelier was working before, it means that the electricity was returning on ground instead of or in addition to the neutral, which is a very wrong way to wire it.
This is how the chandelier should be wired:
This lighting device has lamp cord, which usually consists of two wires under molded insulator plastic.
One of the insulated wires has ribs running down the side of the plastic. This wire is supposed to be connected inside the chandelier to the screw threads of the light sockets, and should be connected to the building's neutral wire.
The other insulated wire has all smooth plastic. This wire is connected inside the chandelier to the center pins on the sockets, and is wired to the building's power wire (usually through a switch).
The third bare wire is the ground. That wire gets connected to the building's ground wire and gets screwed under the mounting metal's ground screw.
Be sure power is off. Remove the insulated lamp cord wire from the grounding screw.
Connect the ribbed-side lamp cord wire to the neutral wires (probably that bundle of white wires).
Connect the smooth-sided lamp cord wire to the building wire that supplies power to the chandelier from the switch.
Connect the bare wire to the grounding screw and the building's ground wire.

Thank you so much. Everything you said makes sense. The cord you are pointing to is hanging free, just appears to be on the screw in the one photo. But your comments are helpful. Thanks again:)

One more thing though. Why would there be three white wires?

+1 for taking the time to explain where hot and neutral should go on a standard socket. OP probably won't (or can't, and/or shouldn't) dig that deep, and it is fairly safe to assume the original manufacturer got the socket wired correctly, but it's not a bad thing to note.

@KevinP. Very often, an electrical box for one device is used as a branch point for other cables going to other places. Your chandelier's box might have further power feeds for other lighting or outlets. In such common cases, many white wires (as well as black wires) might be bundled together.
